# Why is my flex styling going over my nav bar when in mobile

Tags: html, css, flexbox, centering

So I have tried using flex styling to center my page which is what a lot of other experts have been telling me in past forums and never use floats. A lot of people suggest either using grid or flex depending on the situation when reducing the page from desktop to tablet and mobile for responsive website.

Here is what I was attempting to do and I got what I like in desktop.

[image]

Now the text went over the nav bar in mobile. I would like the image to stack on top and the text on the bottom. How do I fix that? And one more thing. When I tap on my hamburger icon, it blocks out the text and I would like to know how you can bring that down below the nav menu when I expand my menu. I know you can use media queries for when it reaches a certain amount of pixels, but I am not sure specifically what code to use. I know there is one that I like for example which is

```
display: block;
```

which works well when it is in a grid instead of flex.

[image]

Take a look at my code and tell me what can I do to fix this issue? Here is where I got the idea from using flex. https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/

**1.** Click on **Both Horizontally and Vertically**

**2.** Then click on **Can you use flexbox**

**HTML**

```html
<div class="flex-Summary">

  <div style="float: left;">
    <img src="img/wallpaper1.jpg" style="width: 170px; height: 170px; border-radius:50%;">
  </div>

  <div style="float: right;">
    <h2>Summary</h2>
    <p style=" font-size: 20px;">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
      in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </P>
  </div>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```css
.flex-Summary {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}
```

Comment: you should first remove float because it's useless then you need to allow the wrap

Comment: Okay, but I would like my image to be on the left and my text on the right while it is still center of the screen as shown in my screenshot. Please feel free to modify my code and then submit it to me when you get a chance.

Answer (score 0):

In cases like this, you need to simplify things. I personally think Grid is overkill for you. Flexbox is sufficient for your layout. I've put together a stripped-down demo for you, including only the necessary `HTML` and `CSS`, so you can see how the layout works.

Some explanation…

First, the flex container is made to be at least the height of the viewport. With that in place, we can focus on the children. I tell the `.content` child to occupy the most space that is available using `flex-grow: 1`. The `nav` implicitly takes up the remaining space, which is what we want. All markup is part of the document flow and takes up "real" space. It seemed like something may have been absolutely positioned in your example, causing the overflow issues in mobile.

As far as vertically centering the image in the content area, I set it to `margin: auto`, which keeps it centered without adding complexity to the `CSS`.

I've included a [link to the Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wzgs5mc2/2/) here, and at the end of my answer.

```css
body, html, p {
  margin: 0;
}

body,
.container {
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

nav {
  padding: 1em;
  background-color: #002eae;
}

nav a {
  color: white;
}

.content {
  background-color: white;
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.content-summary {
  width: 500px;
  max-width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  color: white;
  padding: 1em 1.5em;
  display: flex;
}

.content-summary img {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 150px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <nav>
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    <a href="#">Link 4</a>
    <a href="#">Link 5</a>
  </nav>

  <div class="content">
    <div class="content-summary">
      <img src="https://placekitten.com/200/300" alt="">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
        in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wzgs5mc2/2/